# Use Webfonts in Spotify?

Tags: css, spotify, webfonts

I tried the Google examples for webfonts in my Spotify app. But that didn't seem to work. Spotify comes up with a different font from the one included. No matter which font is linked.

Does this work at all? If yes, how?

Edit:/

Permissions are set for the domains. I also tried to download the font, embed it in the project and use a local url. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web fonts is disabled due to a bug in CEF1 on Windows. We plan on re-introducing it when we move over to CEF3 in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all of the domains used when loading the font in your manifest's `RequiredPermissions` field.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Permissions section at https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/

You will need to add the URLs google web fonts are loaded from to the RequiredPermissions element.

Comment: Permissions are set accurately. That doesn't seem to be the problem. Did it work in your project?